# how to determine CPU types Intel® 64 and IA-32

Tags: x86, intel, cpu-architecture

I'm browsing [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) for memory models, how could I understand which CPU falls to each category? for example, my PC's CPU is Inter(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU ... and system type is 64-bit Operating System, does this belong to Intel® 64 or IA-32 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel 64 is basically a synonym for x86-64 / amd64 / ia-32e.  Or sometimes for a CPU that *can* run in long mode actually running in long mode.  Or maybe also when it's in compat mode (64-bit OS running a 32-bit user-space process).

**Your Haswell CPU is running in Intel 64 mode when you boot a 64-bit OS.**  Like all Intel64 CPUs, it's also capable of running in pure IA-32 mode, so you can boot a 32-bit OS.

Note that IA-64 is something completely different (the discontinued Itanium that lost out to AMD64).

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for links to x86 manuals, including some memory-model stuff.

Comment: Sorry for i'm new here. So do you mean i) `Intel 64` = `x86-64` = `AMD64` = `IA-32e` <> `IA-64`. ii) 64-bit CPU running in 64-bit mode or compact mode (64-bit OS + 32-bit executables) are in `Intel 64` mode. iii)  64-bit CPU booted in 32-bit OS is in `pure IA-32` mode, and iv) `pure IA-32` mode is the `IA-32` in title of the document mentioned above? v) Does `x86-64` mean either `x86` or `x64`?

Comment: @athos: yes, to everything.  Except it's "compatibility mode", not "compact".  And most/all of the IA-32 documentation applies to a process running in compat mode, for its own instructions.

Comment: @athos: more importantly, the x86 memory model is the same in 32 and 64-bit mode.